# Displaying Data from a Select Input from a Modal to a span

Tags: jquery, html

How can display the values of select inputs from a modal to a span outside the modal? This is what I got so far: This is my modal:

```html
#date.modal.inmodal.fade(tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-hidden='true')
  .modal-dialog.modal-m
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        button.close(type='button' data-dismiss='modal')
          span(aria-hidden='true') &times;
          span.sr-only Close
        h4.modal-title Select reporting month
      .modal-body
        .form-group
          h4
            i.fa.fa-calendar
            |  Month
          .selectContainer
            select.form-control(name='month')
              option(value='') Choose a month
              option(value='') January
              option(value='') February
              option(value='') March
              option(value='') April
              option(value='') May
              option(value='') June
              option(value='') July
              option(value='') August
              option(value='') September
              option(value='') October
              option(value='') November
              option(value='') December
        .form-group
          h4
            i.fa.fa-calendar
            |  Year
          .selectContainer
            select.form-control(name='year')
              option(value='') Choose a year
              option(value='') 2017
              option(value='') 2018
      .modal-footer
        button.btn.btn-white(type='button' data-dismiss='modal') Close
        button.btn.btn-primary(type='button') Save
```

And this is the span where I need to display the values of them

```html
h3
  strong
    em CCP Manual testing metrics report 
  br
  span <--- THE SPAN WHERE I NEED THE VALUE OF THE MONTH -->
    em
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign a class to the `span`, for example, `display`. That makes it easier to find it in the document. Following is a way to read the contents from dropdowns and showing them in the span:

```
const month = $("select.form-control[name='month']").val();
const year = $("select.form-control[name='year']").val();

$('span.display').text(`Month: ${month}, Year: ${year}`);
```